# After reading in file in line by line as a string how do I convert the Strings into a Double?

Tags: java, string, double

```
reader = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("bank.txt"));
for(String reader: lines){  
String [] holder = reader.split(("\\s+"));      
Double.parseDouble(reader);
```

The above code throws an error
Updated with space split.

Comment: what error?  Please add your stacktrace

Comment: share your error ?? what's error are you getting??

Comment: so you have to split the line based upon blanks as `130.71 165.31 196.0` is not a double is it

Comment: I tried splitting it but still have the same error

Comment: You're still parsing the same string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse reader which is not a double. Once you get a string array after split, you should be iterating over it and converting one value at a time to double. Here is how:

```
    String [] holder = reader.split(("\\s+"));

    for (String x: holder){
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(x));
    }
```